# how can I include an image file into a gnuplot-generated file?

Tags: gnuplot

I have a small image (*.eps or *.pdf) and want to include it into a gnuplot-generated file (based on regular data). I mean is there any command or trick that would put my external image in like a legend? Using "multiplot" doesn't seem to help; I could not find a good idea in the nice Kawano's site either... Any helpful idea? (Oh, I have gnuplot 4.4 release, and use a 14,04 ubuntu, if this helps...)

Answer (score 0):

I found this similar question:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/27402181/8095033

If you follow the links in there you will find some ways to do it (by using other programs)

I would suggest you to learn some LaTeX, at least the basic and use it to do your work and to gain much more skills (like generating perfect pdf articles or presentations and much more).

PS: texlive on ubuntu (and not only) comes with a command line tool named `convert` that can be used for many changes in the images' format (i.e. eps->png etc)

Comment: thanks! I've by now also found a similar question, and more or less similar (but simpler to me) answer in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28282234

Comment: nice... Glad to hear... In this answer also use latex. If you learn some latex you can do such things much easier and much better than these answers... Take a look at tikz package to see what I mean. You can use it and make almost everything inside of it (and add gnuplot of course when needed)